# maven-shade-plugin relocate classes under META-INF/versions in multi-release jar

Tags: java, maven-3, maven-shade-plugin

I'm using shade to create uber jar. I relocated dependency classes to avoid conflicts. However, I can't find online docs about how to relocate classes under META-INF/versions.

Comment: I found related issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MSHADE-406

Comment: The team started to work on this: https://github.com/apache/maven-shade-plugin/pull/202

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this and it seems to work.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>shade</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        ...
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <manifestEntries>
              <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
            </manifestEntries>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
        <filters>
          <filter>
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              <exclude>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</exclude>
              <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </filter>
        </filters>
        <relocations>
          ...
          <relocation>
            <pattern>META-INF/versions/9/javax.xml.bind</pattern>
            <shadedPattern>META-INF/versions/9/com.example.shaded.javax.xml.bind</shadedPattern>
          </relocation>
        </relocations>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

also met this issue, you can try the solution below:

```
<relocations>
    <relocation>
        <pattern>org/apache/lucene</pattern>
        <shadedPattern>org/apache/relocation/lucene/v811</shadedPattern>
        <rawString>true</rawString>
    </relocation>
</relocations>
```

set the rawString property to ture, and use'/'(not '.')in the pattern/shadedPattern properties.

Answer (score -1):

I found a work-around for this: use `antrun` plugin to unzip final jar, move directories under `META-INF/versions` manually, then repack the jar.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>repack</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <unzip src="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" dest="${project.build.directory}/tmp" />
                            <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/tmp/META-INF/versions/9/your/relocation/prefix" />
                            <move file="${project.build.directory}/tmp/META-INF/versions/9/org" todir="${project.build.directory}/tmp/META-INF/versions/9/your/relocation/prefix" />
                            <zip basedir="${project.build.directory}/tmp" destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar" />
                            <delete dir="${project.build.directory}/tmp" />
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I doubt this will change the package or the import statements of the classes you're moving.

Comment: shade modifies all related class file entries, so the import statements are changed, it's just that the directory structure is not correct. But yours is definitely a better solution. Actually I think shade should handle this situation by itself without extra configuration.